# Use ESP32 as a secure socket

Tags: wifi, esp32

I have a board without network connection, then I bought an SP-WROOM-32 dev kit because it has network connection ability.

Is there any way that I use esp32 as a secure socket (just like calling `socket_connect()` and the ESP will be used?)

I know that my board can control the ESP with AT commands but I want a native way.

Thank and have a nice day.

Comment: Here is a possible starting point: https://github.com/espressif/arduino-esp32/blob/master/libraries/WiFiClientSecure/examples/WiFiClientSecure/WiFiClientSecure.ino

Comment: I am sorry but I want my board use esp32 not esp32 using itself.

Comment: for esp8266 I use WiFi Link, but I do not know if it is portable for ESP32. the WiFi Link firmware is a sketch, so perhaps changing the includes would be all for porting. https://github.com/jandrassy/arduino-library-wifilink/blob/master/README.md

Comment: If programming the ESP32 itself is not "a native way", what is it?

Comment: I want something like calling API of ESP from another board. But it is impossible based on my research.On the other hand, AT commands don't have some features that I need so I will implement another protocol to communicate with ESP. By the way, thank you so much for your time to answering me.

Comment: you can't directly mount the capabilities of an attached device in the main code. you build an API yourself using simple sketches that export the capabilities you need, typically reading requests from serial and writing responses to serial. or you can invert the control and use the ESP to run more of the core logic, to reduce the amount of back-and-forth.